# export 'CHART_TOOL_PANEL_ALLOW_LIST' (imported as 'CHART_TOOL_PANEL_ALLOW_LIST') was not found in 'ag-grid-community'

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

We are changing an Ag Grid **Community** component to **Enterprise**, for which we ran the respective npm command

```
npm install --save ag-grid-enterprise
```

added the import to the enterprise

```
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useRef } from 'react';

import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
```

the expectation was we get enterprise features onboard but now we get to see some error

[image]

package.json also looks fine

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for this issue, this was happening because we need to have the same version of **ag-grid-community** and **ad-grid-enterprise** once upgraded both of them to **V29**, then it worked like a charm.